# How to extract error code from googleapiclient Http Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api-python-client

I have the following code -

```
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
try:
  ...
except HttpError, e: 
  print(str(e))
  if '429' in str(e): 
    # do something
  if '400' in str(e): 
    # do something else
```

it prints the following string -

> <class 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'>, <HttpError 400 when
> requesting
> https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate?alt=json
> returned "The remaining storage in the user's account is not enough to
> perform this operation.">, <traceback object at 0x110379cb0>

I've also looked at HttpError [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/googleapiclient/errors.py), but `e.reason` doesn't work.

I would like to extract error code (`400` in the case above) and reason (`The remaining storage in the user's account is not enough to perform this operation.`)

What is the right approach to get these values?